Render Device: Can't use HIP in Blender 4.1 Flatpak on Fedora 39 Silverblue
I am trying to enable discrete GPU rendering by following these steps:

Open Edit menu
Open Preferences... window (also accessible via Ctrl + , hotkey)
Open System tab
Go to Cycles Render Devices section
Select HIP option

But right now I am getting this error:
No compatible GPUs found for Cycles
Requires AMD GPU with Vega or RDNA architecture
and AMD driver version 22.10 or newer

My PC is an MSI Bravo laptop with these specs:
OS: Fedora Linux 39 (Silverblue) x86_64
Host: Bravo 15 A4DDR (REV:1.0)
Kernel: 6.8.8-200.fc39.x86_64
Packages: 2768 (rpm), 114 (flatpak)
Shell: bash 5.2.26
Display (AUOD0ED): 1920x1080 @ 120Hz [Built-in]
DE: Gnome 45.6
WM: Mutter (Wayland)
Cursor: breeze (24px)
Terminal: GNOME Terminal 3.50.1
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H (16) @ 2,90 GHz
GPU 1: AMD Radeon RX Vega 6 (Ryzen 4000/5000 Mobile Series)
GPU 2: AMD Radeon RX 5500M
Locale: en_GB.UTF-8

Both RX Vega 6 & RX 5500M comply with the requirements.
Here are terminal logs with debug commands:
$ rpm -qa "rocm*|*amd*"
amd-gpu-firmware-20240410-1.fc39.noarch
amd-ucode-firmware-20240410-1.fc39.noarch
xorg-x11-drv-amdgpu-23.0.0-2.fc39.x86_64
rocm-comgr-17.0-3.fc39.x86_64
rocm-runtime-5.7.1-1.fc39.x86_64
rocminfo-5.7.0-1.fc39.x86_64
rocm-device-libs-17.1-1.fc39.x86_64
rocm-hip-5.7.1-1.fc39.x86_64
rocm-clinfo-5.7.1-1.fc39.x86_64

$ flatpak run org.blender.Blender --version
Blender 4.1.1
    build date: 2024-04-15
    build time: 23:47:45
    build commit date: 2024-04-15
    build commit time: 15:11
    build hash: e1743a0317bc
    build platform: Linux
    build type: Release
    build c flags:  -Wall -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wno-stringop-overread -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wnonnull -Wabsolute-value -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable  -std=gnu11 -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2  
    build c++ flags:  -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wcomma-subscript -Wformat-signedness -Wrestrict -Wno-suggest-override -Wuninitialized -Wno-stringop-overread -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations  -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -ffp-contract=off -msse2  
    build link flags:  -Wl,--version-script='/home/blender/git/blender-v410/blender.git/source/creator/symbols_unix.map'
    build system: CMake

$ cat /var/home/tsilvs/.local/share/applications/org.blender.Blender.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Blender (flat)
GenericName=3D modeler
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Icon=org.blender.Blender
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=blender --file-forwarding org.blender.Blender @@ %f @@
Actions=
MimeType=application/x-blender;
Categories=3DGraphics;Graphics;
Keywords=3d;cg;modeling;animation;painting;sculpting;texturing;video editing;video tracking;rendering;render engine;cycles;game engine;python;
StartupWMClass=Blender

Thus I need help troubleshooting this issue to be able to render on GPU.

What I already tried:
$ sudo usermod -a -G video tsilvs
$ sudo usermod -a -G render tsilvs
$ rpm-ostree install rocminfo rocm-clinfo rocm-hip rocm-core

Sources I consulted with:

Linux – AMD - Blender 4.2 Manual
GPU Rendering - Blender 4.1 Manual
How to deal with AMD's new amdgpu-installer 20.40 - Fedora Discussion


This is formatted more like a bug report, which it appears to be. Be warned that the Flatpak is not an official Blender package. I advise you to install snapd and use the Blender snap instead (it will require a symlink and the —classic flag as I recall).

@TheLabCat Snap is not an option as it may and will introduce side effects to my system.
It's either flatpak or rpm.

What kind of side effects?

@TheLabCat First of all, snapd being developped and mainly supported for Ubuntu. Maintainers of Fedora don't support it officially. Therefore I am not willing to try it. It's a very complex piece of software that is by itself yet another package management system.
People also report issues regardless of which distro they're trying to use snap on.

I use Fedora (not Silverblue, though), and have used Snap in general and the Blender snap in particular reliably for some time, through Fedora 38-40 (I have tried other distros in the meantime, though). Snapd is on the official Fedora RPM repository, and is maintained, though you are correct that it is not installed by default. For Linux, only the Snap, Steam, and AppImage releases of Blender are official, and the Flatpak is know to be problematic. I like Flatpak a lot, but with Blender, the Snap is better.
